# How to use PrimeFaces 3.2 in Eclipse Indigo SR2?

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces 3.2. I'm using Eclipse Indigo SR2. I'm creating a JSP page using PrimeFaces tags. The standard `<h:commandButton>` is working, but `<p:commandButton>` is not working.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>

</head>
<body>
<f:view>
        <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Click"></h:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="shfgldjfkl"></p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

My output is this:

[image]

When I'm taking a JSF XHTML page in Indigo Service Release 2, then my code is not running my page is blank.

How can I use PrimeFaces 3.2?

Comment: take a look at this : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world-example/ instead of maven you can place teh jars in your lib folder and add them to your build path

Comment: When taking screenshots, please try to crop out only the *relevant* piece. There's a huge blank space around the lone button in your question which is rather ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

JSP is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0 and succeeded by Facelets. All JSF 2.0 compatible component libraries like PrimeFaces >2.x do not have taglibs for JSP anymore, but only for Facelets.

The `<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">` which you placed in the JSP file won't be recognized by JSP at all. JSF taglibs on XML namespaces work in Facelets only.

[Forget JSP. Concentrate on Facelets.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)

Back to your Facelets problem of a blank page, make sure that you've a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` (otherwise JSF/PrimeFaces won't be able to auto-include the necessary CSS/JS files) and that your request URL matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml` (otherwise `FacesServlet` won't be invoked at all and hence not be able to convert JSF to HTML; you'd have confirmed this by rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser).

Here's the complete Facelets snippet `/demo.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>PrimeFaces demo</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="submit" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

If the `FacesServlet` is in `web.xml` mapped on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you can just open it by the very same filename in the URL without fiddling with virtual URLs like `*.jsf`, `/faces/*`, etc:

> `http://localhost:8080/contextname/demo.xhtml`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should use JSF or facelet personally I never try implementing JSP with primeface, by the way why implement JSP if you can achieve the same result in JSF or facelet so I recommend to move on to JSF 2.0