# primefaces.org/ui cannot be resolved

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I am new to JSF and PrimeFaces (and new to stackoverflow) and am having a configuration/deployment problem.  I am using PrimeFaces 5.0, Tomcat 7.0.55, and JSF 2.2.  The JSF tags can be resolved and work, but the PrimeFaces tags are not resolved and give this error.

Here is the web page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://primefaces.org/ui" prefix="p" %>
<f:loadBundle basename="resources/messages" var="msg"/>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>enter your name page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <f:view>
            <h1>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.inputname_header}"/>
            </h1>
            <h:form id="helloForm">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg.prompt}"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{personBean.personName}" />
                <h:commandButton action="login" value="#{msg.button_text}" />
                <p:spinner />
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error message is:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://primefaces.org/ui cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using JSP. JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0 (at date, almost 5 years ago already). Therefore, JSF 2.0 compatible component libraries don't support JSP anymore. PrimeFaces is such one. Already since PrimeFaces 2.0 it didn't support JSP.

Use JSP's successor **Facelets** instead.

- [Java EE 7 tutorial - Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX)
- [How to use PrimeFaces 3.2 in Eclipse Indigo SR2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954388/how-to-use-primefaces-3-2-in-eclipse-indigo-sr2/)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o/)

Comment: Thank you, that was most helpful.  I've been doing web services and GWT for about 7 years now so I didn't know that JSPs were dinosaurs.  Thank you for cluing me in.  After changing this I found that I also needed to change the faces-config.xml file like this:

Comment: <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">

Comment: That worked and I now have my page with a PrimeFaces tag coming up just fine.  Thank you